# How to exclude screenname in twitter search api

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-search

Im using twitter search api https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets to fetch popular tweets and the result contains @screenname #hashtag and links....., so how to construct api to return tweets without @screenname? and I tried to use "-filter:screenname" to exclude, but its not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "-from:screename"?